# Is there anything in Kabbalah on Supporting a Tzadik?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah

Does the Kabbalah say anything about supporting teachers of the Torah or the Tzadik?

Comment: I think this question needs more clarification as to what you're looking for.

Comment: The concept of being a supporter financially or otherwise of both Torah and its teachers is found in many areas of the Torah literature & tradition. Your question could be improved by explaining further what you mean by “the Tzadik”. Perhaps give a brief example of what type of behavior you are questioning.

Answer (score 1):

The Zohar (Tzav 8) says that a Talmid Chacham, who is devoted to the study of Torah, and doesn’t involve himself in mundane tasks, is on the level of Shabbos, and is therefore a Mitzvah for those who do work to assist him, just like it is a Mitzvah to “assist” the day of Shabbos - in which it is forbidden to do work - by preparing for it during the week, when work is permitted.